# Script in Windows Explorer as Administrator in a folder with special characters

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10

I created a batch file, it worked normally, but I want to avoid future problems, so I created a folder with the following name "New - action_folder"; I run the script and it works, but when I try to open it using the admin user, it opens it does nothing and closes immediately, in another folder, it works, only the folder I created does not work.

This problem, just happens in Windows Explorer, regardless of the command, I already did tests putting just the "pause" command on the bat.

Folder name:

> Nova - pasta_ ação';#@$%¬&()+-.,{}][~~~~

[image]

I recorded a video

https://youtu.be/8O_3vHqqTwg

Comment: When you `Run as administrator` it runs with `%SystemRoot%\system32` as the current directory. If `test.bat` is using relative paths, they will probably not be found in the now current directory. The best solution would involve you actually supplying the content of `test.bat` in your question. You can add that using the [edit facility](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46410073/edit).

Comment: I already solved this, if I run in any other directory, it works, the problem is only in the directory with special characters.

Comment: If I put in the script only "pause", it opens and closes immediately.

Comment: I recorded a video

Comment: The question specifically refers to `New - action_folder\test.bat`, the one which your video shows not working as intended isn't in that directory though, is it? and to be fair anyone who thinks a directory name like the one you're showing is even remotely reasonable deserves their scripts to fail. Please be more realistic with your chosen name and in the meantime add that directory name to your question, so that potential responders don't need to go to YouTube to see it!

Comment: But how to solve?

Answer (score 2):

When you Run as administrator what is actually being run is `cmd.exe /C "%1" %*`

I would assume that this can be improved a little by editing the entry in the registry.

To do so, navigate to the relevant registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas\command
```

and modify the entry to read:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C ""%1" %*"
```

That's it, you're effectively enclosing the entire argument to `cmd.exe` within a separate pair of surrounding double quotes.

Now try your right click entry again and let us know if it has helped any.

*If it worked, then for future proofing I will also suggest making the same change to:*

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\runas\command
```

**Edit**

Here is the batch file for changing the entry, *it needs to be Run as administrator*:

```bat
@Reg Add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas\command" /VE /D "\"%%SystemRoot%%\System32\cmd.exe\" /C \"\"%%1\" %%*\"" /F>Nul
```

Comment: Your idea is good, gave me a direction, but it is still not the solution, because the idea is to run on any machine, I need to send it to someone.

Comment: You could write to Microsoft's development team and ask them to fix it. Other than that, you'll have to either tell 'someone' not to have stupid directory names or provide them with a setup batch file which makes the change first using `Reg Add`. I have added the batch file for doing so to my answer under **Edit**.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to fix this

First do a "shell" with program "Bat To Convert EXE"

That is the "shell"

```
@echo off
call "script.cmd"
```

I will build and mark the option "add manager manifest"

The "shell" was with privilege administrator and you calling your script, like this:

```
@echo off
echo.>new_file.txt
ping 0 -n 2 >nul
FOR %%c in (new_file.txt) do (set cam="%%~dpc")
echo.%cam%>dir.txt
pause

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%F in (dir.txt) do (set linha=%%F
set linha=!linha:"=!
set mypath=!linha!
set mypath=!mypath:^(=^(!
set mypath=!mypath:^)=^)!
set mypath=!mypath:^¬=^¬!

set mypath=!mypath!
echo.!mypath!
cd !mypath!
pause
)
```

Source: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240236/como-executar-um-script-sem-me-preocupar-com-caracteres-especiais